# Performance UICellView with Subviews

Tags: ios, swift

i have a general Question about the Performance of some Custom TableViewCells.

I have 5 different Cells, everyone with a different ReUseIdentifier. That all works fine. Now i need to add a Label on some Cells (its programmatically, and it could be for all of the 5 different Cells).

For Exampe i have now 100 Rows, 20 of each Type and i need to add a Label in the Subview for 10 of the 100 Rows.

It is now better to add the Label programmatically to the Subview of the specific rows, or should i create for 5 different Cells a Label and hide it by default (and use it if needed)

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I will have up to 100 rows. So Performance should be fine. Another Criteria is if i got for example 2 different Subviews (one with a label and one with an image) and i want to hide all images in all rows i could just iterate through my cell.contentviews and hide them. I guess it would be easier just to set up the Views in the Interface Builder and Connect an Outlet and use if needed - but could this bring a performance problem? I could try it out but i guess someone has experience with this requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between adding a subview and unhiding a view or removing a subview and hiding a view is probably not very noticeable.

But from an organizational standpoint, the label should either be added in IB and hidden/unhidden appropriately OR a method for adding the label should be added to the cell, so the cell adds the label itself when this method is called rather than the tableview data source adding the label (and then being responsible for removing it).  If you're adding a subview though, don't forget to remove it in the cell's `prepareForReuse` method.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. If i do it programmatically should i use a different Class for each Cell? And then in "cellForRowAtIndexPath" create a Custom Cell (with the selected Class) and add the Label/Image with a Method provided in the Class as needed?

Comment: They don't necessarily have to be different classes.  You also shouldn't need to create a new object in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.  Just ask the table view to dequeue a cell for you.